# IIS 6.0 web site server output? or server Console? New to IIS 6.0

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, iis-6

Is there a way to enable and see server output on IIS 6.0?

I have deployed my VS 2008 MVC 2 project into IIS 6.0 with wildcard mapping. Static views show up correctly, but database access doesn't work.

My problem is I don't see any error message or error output. So I wonder if I can see server output for my sample web site, that could help me to see what goes wrong?

For example, I will put output before and after connection, the easiest way to debug.

Console.WriteLine("Before connection");

Console.WriteLine("After connection");

However, IIS Manager doesn't allow me to see anything server output except log, which record only GET and POST actions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "server output".  You can have your code write lines to a log file or you can use Visual Studio to attach to the process and debug it that way.

Comment: Thanks. I added log4net trace. At least I got a clue what's wrong. Both Adonet and Nhibernate throw exception as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to log NHibernate information to diagnose a problem, use log4net. See [this article](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx) as reference.

Comment: Thanks. It does have something to do with IIS 6.0 talking with remote sql server. But I can access that server via SSMS with my nt authority/network service. So I don't know what username/password IIS 6.0 used to connect that server.